# I want to pass same value on multiple input boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass same value on multiple input boxes. At the moment below script only display in one box but want show main box result in all multiple input boxes

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$('#main').change(function() {
    $('#catt1').val($(this).val());
});
});//]]>
```

Main input box

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="main" />
```

Multiple inputs

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="catt1" />
```

For example for one - http://jsfiddle.net/SDHNY/

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm stealing that ! :) Brilliant

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Most cars have carpet inside, so that means that JavaScript is one of Java's features, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/SDHNY/321/
You should not use same id for multiple input. Use class for this types of purposes.You should have different name for each input field if you not get value in the jquery by its id and submit it.

**TRY THIS:**

```
Main: <input type="text" name="name_main" id="main" />

<input type="text" name="name" class="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name1" class="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name2" class="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name3" class="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name4" class="catt1" />
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('#main').change(function() {
    $('.catt1').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/SDHNY/319/

```
$('#name').change(function() {
$('input').val($(this).val());
});
```

id should only be used once per page.

If you want to give multiple items an identifier use class

```
class="catt1"
```

from this your code would then change to

```
$('#name').change(function() {
$('.catt1').val($(this).val());
});
```

where the '.' before catt1 signifies to jquery that you are looking for classes not id's

Answer (score 0):

Already a few answers are there, here I am trying to provide a solution using pure javascript without any additional plugins like jQuery,etc..

```js
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("input",function(){
  document.querySelectorAll(".catt1").forEach((e) => e.value = this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="main" />

<input type="text" name="name" class="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name" class="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name" class="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name" class="catt1" />
<input type="text" name="name" class="catt1" />
```